# Equivalent of @ImplementedBy in Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice

What is the equivalent of Guice's @ImplementedBy annotation in Spring DI? (I googled it but with no results.)

Answer (score 2):

There is not exist JIT default binding in Spring. You can set only one implementation to dependency or use naming qualifier @Named or @Qualifier annotation to specify implementation but this is static binding (not equivalent to @ImplementedBy Guice implementation).

I created a spring extension enabling the jit-binding. this library add @ImplementedBy annotation to Spring. See https://github.com/devacfr/spring-implementedby and give me feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation @Qualifier

http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html

Comment: Could you please provide a more elaborated example? Something like http://blog.decaresystems.ie/2007/06/14/juicy-code-with-google-guice-part-4/?